# два docker-compose: как подключиться из одного приложения к другому

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть `docker-compose.yml` первого веб-приложения, в котором есть Nginx:

```
version: '3'
services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    hostname: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      # config
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      # logs
      - ./var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      # sites
      - /home/sitest/www:/var/www
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    command: /bin/sh -c "exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

Тут Nginx слушает 80 и 443 порты и обслуживает первое приложение.

Есть также второе веб-приложение, которое также запускается через docker-compose и построено на основе [Laradock](https://laradock.io/), в нем также есть свой Nginx.

```
nginx:
  build:
    context: ./nginx
    args:
      - CHANGE_SOURCE=${CHANGE_SOURCE}
      - PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER}
      - PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT}
      - http_proxy
      - https_proxy
      - no_proxy
  volumes:
    - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
    - ${NGINX_HOST_LOG_PATH}:/var/log/nginx
    - ${NGINX_SITES_PATH}:/etc/nginx/sites-available
    - ${NGINX_SSL_PATH}:/etc/nginx/ssl
  ports:
    - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80"
  depends_on:
    - php-fpm
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
```

Тут также используется 80 порт, который через `${NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT}` открыт для хост-машины как 8080.

Вопрос: как из первого веб-приложения обратиться ко второму по HTTP?

Хочу провернуть что-то похожее на это:

```
# входим в "первый" nginx
docker-compose exec nginx sh
# внутри вводим хост и получаем данные
wget http://хост-первого-приложения:8080
```